# Using CanCan in engines. Ability.rb example

Tags: ruby, cancan, rails-engines

I'm new in rails development, and I'm trying to create my first engine. This engine could use [CanCan](http://rubygems.org/gems/cancan) for authorization and restricting user's permissions.

I have some permissions in my engine, and I want to inherit them in my main application.

For example:

File `app/models/my_engine/ability.rb` in my engine

```
module MyEngine
  class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability
    def initialize(user)
      user ||= MyEngine::User.new # guest user
      if user.role? "Admin"
        can :manage, :all
      else
        can :read, :all
      end
    end
  end
end
```

File `app/models/ability.rb` in my main application

```
class Ability < MyEngine::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= MyEngine::User.new # guest user
    super(user)
    can :create, SomeModel if user.manager?
  end
end
```

File `app/controllers/my_engine/application_controller.rb`

```
module MyEngine
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def current_ability
       @current_ability ||= MyEngine::Ability.new(current_user)
    end
  end
end
```

But that doesn't work - I get this error if I use the method `can?` in the engine:

```
undefined method `can?'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Some discussion about it on github issue: [ryanb/cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/pull/424)